# Tag Named "Tag" Gives Invalid Qualifier Error - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA Excel, I am trying to change the text of TextBox `Tag` and replace it with the same text but add a number to the end.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? 
**This is my code:**

```
Private Sub One1_Click()
    Tag.Text = Tag.Text & "1"
End Sub
```

The current `Tag.Text` is "iLD". I want to change it to `iLD1` when I click on button `One1`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Tag.Text = Tag.Text & "1"`?

Comment: Nope. Tried that @BruceWayne

Comment: You probably should call your textbox something else like `txtTag`. You may be confusing the compiler because `Tag` could be a reserved word.

Comment: That was it @braX, post an answer below and  I will accept it! I changed it to Asset as it is an asset tag and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should call your textbox something else like `txtTag`. You may be confusing the compiler because `Tag` is a reserved word.